# To find an integral that satisfies a substitution property.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the following integral. $$\int \cfrac{1}{9-x^2}dx$$

Substituting $x=3\sin u$ makes the integral $\displaystyle\int\cfrac{1}{3\cos u}du$.

I would like to modify the original integral such that after the substitution $x=3\sin u$, it looks like $\displaystyle\int\cfrac{1}{9\cos^2u}du$.

My only thought so far was that $dx=3\cos u du$ which tells me that I need to have $\cos^3u$ in the denominator of the integrand to get $\cos^2u$ in the denominator after simplification. How I do proceed from here? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. After substitution in the original integral you get$$\int\frac{3\cos u~du}{9\cos^2u}$$so we want to get an additional $3\cos u$ term in the denominator to cancel the $3\cos u$ in the numerator. Note that $x=3\sin u\implies\sqrt{9-x^2}=3|\cos u|=3\cos u$, so modify the original integral to$$\int\frac{dx}{(9-x^2)\sqrt{9-x^2}}$$

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand how you introduced a 3$\cos u$ in the denominator. Could you explain why $u\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?

Comment: @omololo When $u\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2],3\sin u$ describes the entire range $[-3,3]$ and $\cos u$ is non-negative so that $|\cos u|=\cos u$. Otherwise you may end up getting an unwanted minus sign. You may choose another branch $u\in[2n\pi-\pi/2,2n\pi+\pi/2],n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your time, I can't upvote or "accept" this answer due to lack of reputation.

Comment: Are you sure? The tick-mark button next to my answer has to be pressed to accept it.

Comment: @omololo,   factorize the fraction: $\frac 1{9-x^2}=\frac 1{(3-x)(3+x)}=\frac 16[\frac1{3-x}+\frac 1{3+x}]$.